# Como atribuir os resultados de uma função que retorna uma lista de objetos?

Tags: python, r, funções

No R podemos fazer um função retornar mais de um objeto por meio de uma lista. Mas como fazer para atribuir esses objetos a duas variáveis distintas?

Exemplo:

```
f<-function(){
  primeiro<-1:10
  segundo<-11:21
  return (list(primeiro,segundo))  
}
```

Com a função acima posso atribuir e acessar os objetos da seguinte maneira.

```
d<-f()
d[1]
d[2]
```

Mas não posso atribuir esses valores a variáveis distintas por meio de uma lista

```
list(a,b)<-f()
```

Quero atribuir a cada variável - "a" e "b" - um dos objetos resultados da função f().
O equivalente em Python seria:

```
def f():
    primeiro=range(1,11)
    segundo=range(11,20)
    return (primeiro,segundo)

(a,b)=f()        
print a
print b
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solução que achei mais simples e mais interessante foi definir um outro operador binário (como, por exemplo,`%<-%`  sinalizando uma modificação do `<-` ) que aplique o `assign` em múltilplos argumentos com o `mapply`:

```
`%<-%` <- function(variaveis, valores) {
      mapply(assign, as.character(substitute(variaveis)[-1]), valores, MoreArgs= list(envir = parent.frame()))
      invisible()
    }
```

Assim:

```
list(a,b,c,d) %<-% rnorm(4)
```

Vai gerar quatro variáveis aleatórias,`a`, `b`, `c,` e `d`, com os quatro valores de `rnorm`, por exemplo.

Uma vantagem do `mapply` é que ele já vai reciclar os valores caso eles sejam em menor número do que as variáveis, por exemplo:

```
list(a,b,c,d) %<-% c(1,2)
```

Vai gerar `a=1`, `b=2`, `c=1`, e `d=2`, pois os valores são reciclados.

Ele também vai lidar com o caso de o número de valores ser maior do que o número de variáveis, utilizando os últimos números de valores. Por exemplo:

```
list(a,b,c,d,e) %<-% 1:10
```

Vai atribuir os valores de 6 a 10 às variáveis.

Em suma, é um operador binário com símbolo intuitivo (`%<-%`), com definição simples - apenas uma linha - e que já lida com algumas exceções de uma maneira natural ao `R`. Entretanto, eu evitaria utilizar com frequência este tipo de operação sem antes testar bem para ver se não há outros efeitos colaterais ou comportamentos imprevisíveis.

Answer (score 3):

Nem todas as linguagens de programação oferecem uma maneira sucinta de atribuir valores a mais de uma variável de uma só vez - de uma certa forma, Python é uma exceção.

[Essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519790/assign-multiple-new-variables-in-a-single-line-in-r) no Stackoverflow em inglês documenta algumas das maneiras de aproximar a atribuição múltipla em R. Se você quiser muito você pode usar algo sugerido lá mas a impressão que eu tenho é que talvez valha a pena escrever da forma mais simples e com menos mágica, apesar de ser um pouco mais longo

```
d <- f()
a <- d[1]
b <- d[2]
```

Answer (score 3):

[Nessa resposta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15140507/520779) o autor propõe uma estrutura para permitir construções desse tipo. [Aqui está a postagem original](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2004-June/053343.html) (também em inglês). O código sugerido é:

```
list <- structure(NA,class="result")
"[<-.result" <- function(x,...,value) {
   args <- as.list(match.call())
   args <- args[-c(1:2,length(args))]
   length(value) <- length(args)
   for(i in seq(along=args)) {
     a <- args[[i]]
     if(!missing(a)) eval.parent(substitute(a <- v,list(a=a,v=value[[i]])))
   }
   x
}
```

E alguns exemplos de uso:

```
list[a, b] <- funcaoRetornandoDoisValores()
list[a] <- funcaoRetornandoDoisValores()
list[a, ] <- funcaoRetornandoDoisValores()
list[, b] <- funcaoRetornandoDoisValores()

list[QR,,QRaux]  <- qr(c(1,1:3,3:1))
list[,Green,Blue]  <- col2rgb("aquamarine")

a <- 1; b <- 2
list[a,b] <- list(b,a) # Troca a e b

require(chron)
list[Month, Day, Year] <- month.day.year(unclass(Sys.Date()))
```

(Note que você pode obter todos os valores de retorno, ou ignorar aqueles que não te interessam)

Há diversas outras opções na mesma pergunta linkada (e na resposta do @missingno) mas essa forma foi a que na minha opinião produz um código mais limpo.